# It's possible to use any borderless custom marker for AR.js

Tags: augmented-reality, ar.js

I am using custom marker for AR.js which is working fine, But I need to create a black border less or margin less custom marker for my project but when i create it along with it's pattern it's not effected rather it's detect the old custom marker. Please help me if it's possible.